# Tasker plugin android studio on recieve

Tags: java, android, сокет, плагин

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь написать плагин для таскера который будет отправлять сокеты на указанный ип:порт с определённым сообщением.

Т.к. в андроид и ява туп как дуб использовал рабочий проект с гитхаба: https://github.com/nosybore/Tasker-MQTT-Publish-Plugin

Поменял поля переменные и переписал код внутри самого обработчика:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    mServer = intent.getStringExtra("Server");
    mPort = intent.getStringExtra("Port");
    mMessage = intent.getStringExtra("Payload");

    mMessage += "\r\n";

    try {
        //Send Socket
        if(mServer != "" && mPort != "" && mMessage != "") {
            Socket socket = new Socket(mServer, parseInt(mPort));
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeUTF(mMessage);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            socket.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Socket Sended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

В таскере плагин видится настройки добавляются но при запуске не происходит ничего. Пробовал вывести Toast - не выводится так же ничего. Ч.я.д.н.т.?(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так всё оказалось очень сложно. Может кому пригодится информация.

1). Для использования java.sockets нужно в манифесте прописать:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

2). Андроид запрещает вызывать функции работы с сетью из главного потока. Поэтому создаём новый класс с конструктором:

```
class SendSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String sMessage;
private int sPort;
private String sIpaddress;

public SendSocket(String msg, int prt, String ipaddress) {
    sMessage = msg;
    sPort = prt;
    sIpaddress = ipaddress;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(sIpaddress, sPort);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeUTF(sMessage);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

И вызываем его в onReceive:

```
SendSocket newSS = new SendSocket(mPayload, port, mServer);
newSS.execute();
```